# TimeoutException using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, timeoutexception

I'm getting a timeout exception when trying set some variables inside of the proxy/channel I opened.
I'm not sure if it's a bad DataContract or something I haven't set correctly.

Here is the Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommandBoardService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Hello();

    [OperationContract]
    Command_Board.States getState();

    [OperationContract]
    void setState(Command_Board.States s);

    [OperationContract]
    string setConnected(int i);

    [OperationContract]
    int getConnected();

}
```

Here is the Service Class:

```
public class CommandBoardService : ICommandBoardService
{
    [DataMember]
    public Command_Board.States state;

    [DataMember]
    public int connected = 0;

    public void Hello()
    {
    }

    public Command_Board.States getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Command_Board.States s)
    {
        state = s;
    }

    public string setConnected(int i){
        connected += i;
        return "Player "+connected+" Connected";
    }

    public int getConnected(){
        return connected;
    }
}
```

and here is where I'm opening up the host and calling the proxy:

```
            ICommandBoardService proxy;
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommandBoardServiceLibrary.CommandBoardService)))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(
                    CommandBoardServiceLibrary.ICommandBoardService),
                    new NetTcpBinding(),
                    "net.tcp://localHost:9000/CommandBoardEndPoint");
                host.Open();


                proxy = ChannelFactory<ICommandBoardService>.CreateChannel(
                             new NetTcpBinding(),
                            new EndpointAddress(
                            "net.tcp://localhost:9000/CommandBoardEndPoint"));

                proxy.setConnected(0);
                proxy.setState(state);
            }
```

I get the following error when I reach `proxy.setConnected(0)` and even when I flip them around I get the same error with `proxy.setState(state)`

This is the error:

`This request operation sent to net.tcp://localhost:9000/CommandBoardEndPoint did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.`

What can I do to fix the error? 
Some people have said increase the max buffer, but I don't know how to do that using WinForms.

Comment: All your code does is increment a variable. I don't see why it would take 1 minute to do this. I'm assuming the problem is happening somewhere else. Enable tracing and see if you get anything in the trace log.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange , I've never enabled tracing before. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Just google "how to enable tracing wcf".

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, Yea I'm watching some videos. The strange this is that when using the same code somewhere else, I get the expected result.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @TomW, I did solve it. For some reason letting my host be a winform app didn't allow the service be seen by anyone. So I turned the host into a console app and everything resolved itself. AND I am still able to host and create the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

you'd increase the maxBufferSize in your app.config under the binding properties

```
<binding name="blah"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" -- Max int size
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the host and creating the proxy on the same thread. I'd be surprised if that works; I can't see how the host could ever actually execute anything. The client will wait synchronously for an answer from the host - which can't ever give one, because it could only ever do that work on the thread the client is using.

Solution, I think, is to use one of the many different multithreading methods available in .net to spin up the host in a separate thread so that both can do their work concurrently.